# IE10 / Edge PDF not showing correct values

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, pdf, microsoft-edge

So I have a PDF that has been created on the fly by opening a template, modifying the values for certain fields, and then saved.

Works:

- If I open the file in Chrome, I have the correct values.
- If I save the file to disk and open it with Adobe Reader DC (or whatever that's called), I get the correct values.

Doesn't Work:

- When I open the document in IE 10, it opens in Edge, and shows "default" values for the fields.
- When I save the file to disk and open it with IE, it shows "default" values.
- When I open the file using "PDF reader - Document Viewer and Manager" it shows "default" values.

I'm using Windows 10, the application I'm working on is done in ASP.Net. It works the same way whether I return a FileStreamResult, FilePathResult, or File.

And I'm now pretty much certain the problem is Microsoft's products and not my code.

Any idea why Microsoft products are incapable of opening my PDFs correctly?  Do they have to be flattened in some specific way or something?

Edit (more information as requested in comments):

- The documents are created using PdfSharp.
- They have fields that are dynamically replaced with values (i.e. [MyFieldA] is replaced with "ActualValueA").
- Once the merge fields are replaced with actual values, the file is written using `File.WriteAllText(fileName,fileText);` where fileText is obtained through `File.ReadAllText(fileTemplateName);`

Image of comparison of fields that are wonky:
[image: Comparison]

Comment: You have to include more details on how you create your documents and how you fill the data that seems to be missing under IE.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I added some more information at the bottom of the post.  I'm digging into the document creation process for the first time, and will keep updating with information as I find it.  One theory that was posited by a coworker was that the document templates are created in Acrobat 5, which IE10/Edge is unable to deal with sufficiently, because another coworker was having issues with templates that were created in Acrobat 6 (which are compatible with IE10/Edge).

Comment: Please share a sample PDF to illustrate the issue for analysis.

Comment: I can't do that due to NDA.  I'll give a screen shot of a piece of pdfs though

Comment: @mkl - I added a snippet of differences.  This is the exact same place in the exact same file as displayed when opened with different programs.

Comment: How about that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14965242/combining-pdfs-with-pdfsharp-losing-form-fields

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I think we solved the issue though, I'll have to do some more testing in the morning just to make sure.  But in a nutshell, it appears that you can't have default display values in form fields and Microsoft Edge (or PDF viewer through the app store thing) be able to pick up the actual values.  When ALL of the default values were deleted from the template, Edge was able to show the values.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution to the problem, and it appears that it might be a two-fold thing.

One piece of the puzzle I believe was the memorystream being used to create the PDF.  It was declared in an inner scope, used in a PdfReader.Open call in an assignment to a var that was declared in an outer scope, and then the scope ended, while the var was still being used.  I moved the memorystream declaration to the outer scope where the var declaration was so that they would be in the same scope.  Also, the memorystream wasn't being closed with a `memoryStream.Close()` call or in a `using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) { }` block.  So I added a call to `memoryStream.Close()`.

The other piece is that the PDF template form fields had some default display values.  It appears that Microsoft stuff (Edge, PDF Viewer) may not be able to get the inserted values, and is instead reading the default display values of the fields and displaying those.  Once all of the default display values were removed, Edge began opening the PDF and displaying values correctly.

Since these two pieces were done in tandem, I can't say for certain that they both play an equal role in this, but these are the only two changes that were done to get values to start displaying correctly.  My gut feeling is that the problem lies with the default display values and Edge.

Comment: Concerning the first possible cause: As you have shown no usable piece of code in your question, no-one could have given a hint in that direction without guessing wildly. Concerning the second possible cause: PDF form fields can provide an appearance stream (concerning a layout'ed field content) in addition to the plain field value. A viewer then may choose to display that pre-layout'ed appearance stream or create one from scratch using the plain field value. Probably such appearance streams are your *default display values*. Beware, there are previewers that cannot create one from scratch.

Comment: That is highly likely.  I ran into this bug blindly, having not worked in this area previously.  I just happen to be the "bug bulldog" of the group that can't let it go until it's resolved.