# Combining Fillable Pdf-forms using PdfSharp

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, pdf-form

When I try to combine 2 fillable pdf-forms using pdfsharp the form filling capability of the combined file is lost.
Is this a bug or am i missing something.
Really appreciate any help.

Comment: You should share with us your relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search of this site has revealsed that pdfsharp does not support it fully.

[Combining PDFs with PDFSharp losing form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14965242/combining-pdfs-with-pdfsharp-losing-form-fields)

However this question is a few years old so may not be totally accurate. That persons suggestion was to use ITextSharp instead